Cant output multiple components
I'm building an app with shadcn ui including data fetching with json server. The end result only gives out one card instead of multiple i expect it to be. And even first card doesnt show with correct details (from json file)
import{
  Card, 
  CardHeader, 
  CardFooter, 
  CardTitle, 
  CardDescription, 
  CardContent
} from '@/components/ui/card'

interface Recipe {
  title: string,
  image: string,
  time: number,
  description: string,
  vegan: boolean,
  id: string
}


async function getRecipes(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
  const result = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/recipes');
  return result.json()
  
}


export default async function Home() {
  const recipes = await getRecipes()
  
  return (
    <main> 
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8">
        {recipes.map(recipe =>(
          <Card key={recipe.id}>
            <CardHeader>
            <div>
              <CardTitle>{recipe.title}</CardTitle>
              <CardDescription>{recipe.time} mins to cook </CardDescription>
            </div>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardContent>
              <p>{recipe.description}</p>
            </CardContent>
            <CardFooter>
              <button> View Recipe</button>
              {recipe.vegan && <p>Vegan!</p>}
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}


I felt like this is correct way to data fetch, but it doesnt work yet
Page.tsx
{
    "recipes":[
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Recipe1",
            "image": "Recipe1",
            "time": 10,
            "description": "Recipe1 description.",
            "vegan": true
        },

        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Recipe2",
            "image": "Recipe2.jpg",
            "time": 20,
            "description": "Recipe1 description.",
            "vegan": false
        }






    ]

My json file (_data/db.json), it doesnt output with multiple cards , and first card doesnt come up with Recipe1 title, "10 time" either.

Since the .tsx i'l asume you are using React.
The JSON seems to have an extra nesting level which might not align with the expected structure in your fetch function. The JSON should look like this:
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Recipe1",
    "image": "Recipe1",
    "time": 10,
    "description": "Recipe1 description.",
    "vegan": true
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Recipe2",
    "image": "Recipe2.jpg",
    "time": 20,
    "description": "Recipe2 description.",
    "vegan": false
}
]

Also, the fetch function should handle errors:
async function getRecipes(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/recipes');
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch recipes');
  }
  return response.json();
}

You have to make sure you're handling any asynchronous operations correctly. You can use useEffect and useState for better state management in a React component.
So, try this:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Card, 
  CardHeader, 
  CardFooter, 
  CardTitle, 
  CardDescription, 
  CardContent
} from '@/components/ui/card';

interface Recipe {
  title: string,
  image: string,
  time: number,
  description: string,
  vegan: boolean,
  id: string
}

async function getRecipes(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/recipes');
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch recipes');
  }
  return response.json();
}

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState<Recipe[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipes = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getRecipes();
        setRecipes(data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError('Failed to load recipes');
      }
    };
    fetchRecipes();
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>{error}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <main> 
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8">
        {recipes.map(recipe => (
          <Card key={recipe.id}>
            <CardHeader>
              <div>
                <CardTitle>{recipe.title}</CardTitle>
                <CardDescription>{recipe.time} mins to cook</CardDescription>
              </div>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardContent>
              <p>{recipe.description}</p>
            </CardContent>
            <CardFooter>
              <button>View Recipe</button>
              {recipe.vegan && <p>Vegan!</p>}
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;


I did use Nextjs for this app ,http://localhost:4000/recipes link currently outputs a Not Found! screen for me with current api status. And right now im using client component so UseState doesnt work , should i change that as well?

Ensure your JSON server is running correctly and serving the data at localhost:4000/recipes. The db.json file should be in the correct format!
You have two options: Change the component to a client component or move the fetch to an API Route
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
I usually stick with the latest, but you can go with a client components if its ok for your project

Also, the code above is working for me, so it should work if your JSON server is running and you put a "use client" on top.
